Intellisense Function Argument Completion Issues C++
ss1
Intellisense is able to figure out what method I'm trying to override (I'm coding for Unreal Engine). However, when I press tab/enter/ctrl+space, it does not autocomplete the definition in the header file. I have to type all of the arguments by looking at it. I'm not sure if this is directly related to Visual Studio, but I tried the same thing on 10x Editor and result is the same. It is able to determine the function members correctly, however the code completion does not work.
I've tried various solutions. Reinstalled whole VS environment including the C++ packages, it is still the same. I've checked "auto list members" on Tools -> Options -> C++, I've checked Intellicode settings and they seem OK.
Does anyone have any idea about this issue and how can I fix it? I can provide any extra information you need.
